# SSIS Sort task (data flow)

Tags: sorting, ssis, dataflowtask

I have a package where I am sorting by Aged Months column, I am not doing any other thing to filter the data and I am not removing duplicates, but once the data flow passes the Sort task the output rows are much less than the input. (1.218.206 rows in - only 53,344 out) any clue what's happening here?

[image]

Comment: What is the sort type and sort order?
Are you sure the box 'Remove rows with duplicate sort values' isn't checked?

Comment: Are you sorting by just the Aged Months column? You may need to add a column to the Sort to pull back everything.

Comment: @DrHouseofSQL    The box of "Remove .." Is unchecked.  I am only sorting for Aged Months but passing all the columns.

Comment: Ascending or Descending? What number is in the Sort Order?

Comment: @DrHouseofSQL  ascending sort order 1

Answer (score 1):

I just solved it, I removed  a derived column at the end of the package with some calculations and now all data get loaded into my destination. it doesn't make any sense since the derived column is way below the sorting task but for some reason that worked.

Thank you @DrHouseofSQL